# Plotting PCA biplot with autoplot: modify arrow thickness

Tags: r, pca, ggfortify, biplot

I am using the `autoplot` function from `ggfortify` as illustrated by the code below using `iris.pca`. This example only has three variables (hence 3 loadings) but my data set has a lot more variables so I wish I could reduce the size of the arrows to make the plot more readable. I think the default size is 1 pt and I'd like to get it down to something like 0.5. Although there are arguments to modify the loadings color and label size, I could not find a way to adjust the thickness of the arrows. Does anyone knows how to do this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]
iris.pca<-(prcomp(df))

autoplot(iris.pca, data=iris, colour="Species", loadings=TRUE, loadings.colour = "black")+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("forestgreen","red","blue"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("forestgreen","red","blue"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(25,22,23))+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Hello, please provide a reproducible example so we can all see what you are trying to do with `iris.pca`.

Comment: I edited my question. The example using `iris.pca` is just to illustrate what plot I am talking about. In my case I have more variables and I feel reducing the thickness of the arrows would help readability.

Comment: Please also provide the code to produce `iris.pca`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that part. I added it to the code now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `ggfortify` has already created a ggplot2 object. So if you don't want to recreate the plot by hand (which would be the cleaner solution here), you have to modify the existing plot in the following way:

### Old code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]
iris.pca<-(prcomp(df))

d <- autoplot(iris.pca, data=iris, colour="Species", loadings=TRUE, loadings.colour = "black", scale = 1)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("forestgreen","red","blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("forestgreen","red","blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(25,22,23))+
  theme_bw()
```

### Modifications

```
d$layers[[2]]$aes_params$size <- 0.5
d$layers[[2]]$geom_params$arrow$length <- unit(6, units = "points")
d
```

This essentially manually creates the size aesthetic for the arrow lines, and shrinks the pointy ends of the arrows: [image: Resulting Plot]

Comment: I think OP asked for thickness, not length?

Comment: "Length" refers to the size of the arrowhead. If you make the lines thinner, for visual completeness you should also make the arrowheads smaller.

Comment: Don’t know how I overlooked the `size` — thanks for the clarification!